# Class member variable and method name collision

Tags: ruby, member-access

I am working with a 3rd party library where I'm trying to access a class member variable but unfortunately there is also a method with the same name.

```
class Test
  attr_writer :var

  def var
    "some other stuff that is not var"
  end
end

test = Test.new()

# Returns result of function but I need variable contents
test.var
```

Unfortunately I cannot change this since it's 3rd party.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do..?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Instance variables and methods have different namespaces, instance variables *always* start with `@`, methods *never* start with `@`, there *cannot* possibly be a name collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get):

```
test = Test.new
test.instance_variable_get(:@var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reader-method with other name:

```
class Test
   def var_reader
       @var
   end
end
```

This may be better, than directly using instance_variable_get, if you need it more than once or may need some additional logic around

On ruby-2.1+ this can be more elegant with a refinement:

```
module TestRefinement
  refine Test do
    def var_getter
      @var
    end
  end
end

using TestRefinement
a.var_getter
```